Почему нулевой индекс выходит за индексацию?
Я пишу игру, с генерацией пароля и последующим его взломом игроком. При каждой неудачной попытке, выводится кол - во правильных символов в предложенном варианте, ну должно. А по итогу вылетает ошибка, которая гласит index out of range, хотя при этом i это 0, а длинна строки не может быть больше 4 чисто физически, функции выполняються последовательно. Как это происходит? Вот код функции:
def CorrectOrNot():
    global password
    global gamer_password
    simvols = 0
    if password == gamer_password:
        print("Верный пароль! Доступ разрешен!")
    else:
        print("Неверный пароль!")
        for i in range(len(gamer_password)):
            if gamer_password[i] == password[i]:
                simvols + 1
        print("Совпало f{simwols} из 4")


добро пожаловать! Ошибку в студию) Нажмите [edit] под вопросом и добавьте

Если gamer_password или password пустое, то такая ошибка вполне логичная

@andreymal, если gamer_password пустой, никакой ошибки не будет, ведь у нас итерация по пустой строке. Однако мне интересно было бы посмотреть, как вы принимаете input пользователя, для gamer_password. Добавьте свой код. Очевидно одно, что ошибка возникает в том случае, если выполняется следующее условие -> len(gamer_password) > len(password)

у вас наверное пустой password
